# how to use namespace in wordpress, while use its root file class

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used namespace in my WordPress plugin program, how can I use WordPress default class while using namespace, for me it was showing error.

this is my code

problem 1.

```
namespace Example\Test;

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php' );

class newTest {
   public function __construct(){
     $upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
   }
 }
```

In this case, it was showing Example\Test\Plugin_Upgrader is not found.

problem 2.

```
namespace Example\Test;

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php' );

class Example_Upgrader_Skin extends WP_Upgrader_Skin {

   public function feedback( $string ) {
    // @note: Keep it empty.
   }
}
```

In this case, also showing same error Example\Test\WP_Upgrader_Skin is not found.

please give me solution for this am I doing it right? can I use namespace in this case?

Comment: If i recall you just need to use \ before the class name as in `new \Plugin_Upgrader` Or you add `use Plugin_Upgrader` when importing.

Comment: thank you so much, sorry actually this is the first time I am using namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  **Chris Morris** suggestion i am writing answer here.

```
namespace Example\Test;

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php' );

class newTest {
  public function __construct(){
   $upgrader = new \Plugin_Upgrader();
 }
}
/**************************************/
namespace Example\Test;

 include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php' );

 class Example_Upgrader_Skin extends \WP_Upgrader_Skin {

    public function feedback( $string ) {
         // @note: Keep it empty.
  }
 }
```